# for range Images are overlaid in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to upload images one after another on the web
like this
01.image
02.image
03.image

bytheway, the results are overlapping.
(01.image)
(01.image,02.image)
(01.image,02.image,03.image)

It will be mounted like this

```
>>>>>>>>>>> code <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

def find_file(number, selected_dir):  #serch image
    image = []
    goal = number
    input_list = goal.split()
    input_list = [str(a) for a in input_list]

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(selected_dir):
        for name in files:
            for search_word in goal:
                if goal in name:
                    image.append(os.path.join(root, name))
                    break
    return image       

 
        
        
imagearr = find_file(str(excel_arr[i][0]), r"C:/test/img")
time.sleep(2)
        
for j in range(0,len(imagearr)):
    if j>9:
       break
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="input-img-file"]').send_keys(imagearr[j])
    time.sleep(1)

----  result

 1. 01.image   insert
 2. 01.image, 02.image   insert
 3. 01.image, 02.image  03.image   insert

results overlap...


I want ..
  

 1. 01.image   insert
 2. 02.image   insert
 3. 03.image   insert


I'm asking for help**
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcqGy.jpg)

Comment: Can you explain `driver.find_element`?  Looks like you are using PySelenium.

Comment: The element value of the button is like this           <input data-v-3d099bc1="" type="file" multiple="multiple" id="input-img-file" name="input-img-file" size="chars" accept="image/png,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/gif">

Comment: `for search_word in goal:` is going to loop for each *character* in `goal` (NOT word).  If `goal in name` is true, then you will append the filename to your list once for each of those characters.

Comment: @jasonharper  Other sites run fine